# Modifying each element in a list in a function

Tags: python, function

I am a new programmer learning python with Codeacademy and I am supposed to create a function double_list that returns the items in list n and multiplies each number by 2. Every time I run the code I get the error: ' double_list([0, 1]) returned [0, 1] instead of [0, 2]'

```
n = [3, 5, 7]

def double_list(x):
  for i in range(0, len(x)):
    x[i] = x[i] * 2
    return x

print double_list(n)
```

Comment: Just pull out one indent before your "return". You currently return your value within the loop so that only the first item is multiplied.

Answer (score 4):

Your function can only `return` once, so you need to back it out of the `for` loop. As written, your function currently will `return x` after the first iteration, so none of the remaining elements are modified.

```
def double_list(x):
    for i in range(0, len(x)):
        x[i] = x[i] * 2
    return x
```

An alternative, by the way, is to use a simple list comprehension, this will **not modify the original list** and will create a new one that you can assign back to the original variable if you'd like

```
def double_list(x):
    return [i*2 for i in x]

>>> n = [3, 5, 7]
>>> n = double_list(n)
>>> n
[6, 10, 14]
```

If you prefer to **modify the actual list argument**, you can use change the function to

```
def double_list(x):
    for index, value in enumerate(x):
        x[index] = 2 * value

>>> n = [3, 5, 7]
>>> double_list(n)
>>> n
[6, 10, 14]
```

Comment: I also strongly recommend using a list comprehension rather than mutating the list in-place, however if you're going to change the list in-place, it's unnecessary to `return` AT ALL (much how `list.sort()` returns `None` -- it's just an in-place mutation)

Comment: @AdamSmith To make this more clear, I edited my post to show each method.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it very easy with list comprehension.

```
n = [3, 5, 7]

def double_list(x):
  return [y*2 for y in x]

print double_list(n)
'[6, 10, 14]'
```

Comment: CoryKramer answered before me, you should accept his answer. good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

This is an easy way to do it using `map`:

```
>>> n = [3, 5, 7]
>>> def double_list(x):
        return x * 2

>>> map(double_list, n)
[6, 10, 14]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

use map can simply it:

```
n = map(lambda x: 2*x, n)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
n = [3, 5, 7]

def double_list(x):
  for i in range(0, len(x)):
    x[i] = x[i] * 2
    return x

print double_list(n)
```

You just need to change `n` to `x` in the above line and you'll pass through this exercise

Answer (score -1):

You can simply do this:

```
n = [3, 5, 7]
def double_list(x):
    for i in range(0, len(x)):
        x[i] = x[i] * 2
        for j in range(1, len(x)):
            x[j] = x[j] * 2
            for k in range(2, len(x)):
                x[k] = x[k] * 2
        return x
# Don't forget to return your new list!

print double_list(n)
```